# Why doesn't posn work as a constructor in Racket?

Tags: racket

The "extra" constructor *make-posn* works. Why not *posn* by itself? Thanks.

I want to use it for *place-images*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make `posn` available by adding this to the beginning of your definitions.

```
(define (posn x y)
  (make-posn x y))
```

The reason why is mostly historical.

Back in time the constructor for a struct `foo` was named `make-foo`. At some point it was changed to just `foo`. Since the teaching languages was used in books and other educational materials the convention `make-foo` wasn't changed.

Since `posn` normally is used from the teaching languages, the constructor with the name `posn` was hidden on purpose.

Note that you can't "cheat the system" and use:

```
#lang racket
(struct posn (x y))
call drawing operations here
```

Each time `(struct posn ...)` is seen a new type of `posn`-structure is defined. Using `(posn ...)` here will construct your version of `posn`-structures and the drawing operations expect those from the teaching languages - so this will lead to an error.

Comment: What I don't understand is how the natural posn constructor got hidden.

Comment: @RussAbbott I have added some more information to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In fact I tried to declare my own posn and found (as you said) that it wouldn't work with place-images, which is how this whole thing came up. (I typed in "@soegaard" to attempt to respond but the tag disappeared. Sorry. I guess I don't know how to make a tag.)

Comment: @RussAbbott I get notification automatically when comments are made to an answer. I can't remember if that's default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a stundent language I assume? In `#lang racket`
 you use `(struct ...)` instead of e.g. `(define-struct ...)` to define structures and similarily `(posn ...)` instead `(make-posn ...)`.

Comment: I'm using standard racket, not a student language. Also, it's supposed to be defined already. I should not have to define it.